# How to migrate the content of one disk on a Raid5?

Tags: debian, raid, raid5

I have one 1.5Tb HDD with Debian Wheezy. I have also four 2Tb empty HDDs.

I want to configure the four 2Tb disks in Raid5 and install LVM. Then migrate the content of the 1.5Tb disk on the Raid5.

Before starting, I would like to know if the migration could be possible and, if yes, how to do it.

Comment: Is LVM used on the old HDD? Do you want to do the migration live (no shutdown or interruption of service)?

Comment: No, LVM is not used on the old HDD. Migration off line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do a 'rsync' from the old disk to the new disk. 
Something like this should work:

```
rsync -rtv "/mnt/old_drive" "/mnt/new_drive"
```

You would replace the above locations with the mount points of your disks on your computer.

To find where your disks are mounted to or what device they are showing up as you can use:

```
df -h
```

and...

```
cat /proc/diskstats
```

'df' will tell you where the disks are mounted and 'cat /proc...' will tell you what devices the disks are connected as in case you have to mount them manually or add them to fstab.

Comment: /mnt/mt0 for me ? and LVM ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You would replace '/mnt/old_drive' and '/mnt/new_drive' with the location of your disks mount points. ...ill edit the answer a little to help with this.

Comment: Here is a link to a tutorial on how to setup a LVM: http://ostechnix.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/linux-basics-lvm-logical-volume-manager-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Safest solution might be to configure your RAID5/LVM disks then reboot the system using a live cd having gparted on it (see http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).  You can then clone your partitions onto the LVM volumes quite easily.

Comment: good idea ! I will try that.

Comment: I don't know this tool but is it also possible to move a directory (i.e /var) into a LVM partition (i.e p_var) ?